# Getting an exception in WebSphere 8 when MDB try to connect to Remote Queue

Tags: java, ejb, ibm-mq, websphere-8

When a message is dropped in the Queue we are getting below error in Websphere 8.

Now, if we restart the server everything works fine all the messages in the queue. But after the Queue is empty and when new messages are dropped in the Queue then for sometime it works and after that it is throwing below error.

Any thoughts on why this is happening?

```
[2/7/13 20:20:41:363 PST] 0000001e LocalTranCoor E   WLTC0017E: Resources rolled back due to setRollbackOnly() being called.
[2/7/13 20:20:41:425 PST] 0000009a SibMessage    W   [:] CWSJY0003W: JMSCC0110: An exception '
                       Message : java.lang.NullPointerException
                         Class : class java.lang.NullPointerException
                         Stack : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.MQSession.consume(MQSession.java:1943)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.MQSession.loadMessageReference(MQSession.java:4442)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.consume(JmsSessionImpl.java:3199)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.run(JmsSessionImpl.java:2838)
                               : com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession.run(MQSession.java:862)
                               : com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSSessionHandle.run(JMSSessionHandle.java:1057)
                               : com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.ServerSession.connectionConsumerOnMessage(ServerSession.java:1085)
                               : com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.ServerSession.onMessage(ServerSession.java:755)
                               : com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.ServerSession.dispatch(ServerSession.java:721)
                               : sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor22.invoke(null:-1)
                               : sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
                               : java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
                               : com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.ServerSessionDispatcher.dispatch(ServerSessionDispatcher.java:47)
                               : com.ibm.ejs.container.MDBWrapper.onMessage(MDBWrapper.java:98)
                               : com.ibm.ejs.container.MDBWrapper.onMessage(MDBWrapper.java:135)
                               : com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.ServerSession.run(ServerSession.java:580)
                               : com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1659)
' was caught while processing a message for delivery to a message driven bean.
[2/7/13 20:20:41:425 PST] 0000009a LocalExceptio E   CNTR0020E: EJB threw an unexpected (non-declared) exception during invocation of method "onMessage" on bean "BeanId(JBoomerang#JBoomerangEJB.jar#LNPGWStatusResponseMDB1, null)". Exception data: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor22.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
                at com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.ServerSessionDispatcher.dispatch(ServerSessionDispatcher.java:47)
                at com.ibm.ejs.container.MDBWrapper.onMessage(MDBWrapper.java:98)
                at com.ibm.ejs.container.MDBWrapper.onMessage(MDBWrapper.java:135)
                at com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.ServerSession.run(ServerSession.java:580)
                at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1659)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.MQSession.consume(MQSession.java:1943)
                at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.MQSession.loadMessageReference(MQSession.java:4442)
                at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.consume(JmsSessionImpl.java:3199)
                at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.run(JmsSessionImpl.java:2838)
                at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession.run(MQSession.java:862)
                at com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSSessionHandle.run(JMSSessionHandle.java:1057)
                at com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.ServerSession.connectionConsumerOnMessage(ServerSession.java:1085)
                at com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.ServerSession.onMessage(ServerSession.java:755)
                at com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.ServerSession.dispatch(ServerSession.java:721)
                ... 8 more
```

Comment: this was working fine when we were on websphere 6. when i migrated this to 8 then it is failing

Comment: I got this Link.... dont know whether this can be a problem...   http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IV13714

Comment: Might a PMR be possible?

Comment: Did you try to print the linked exception and if so what did it say?

Comment: So Akhilesh, can we treat this question as abandoned?  Without the linked exception or responses to requests for more info, it can be answered only with vague guesses and that doesn't help you or the site.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you that this looks like a match for IV13714. Looking at the page for that (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IV13714) I can see that IBM shipped the fix for it in MQ 7.0.1.9.

Since you're in a WAS environment that means you need to upgrade to a version of WAS 8.0.0 which ships MQ 7.0.1.9+.

IBM detail this information here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21248089

So putting all that together, looks like you need to upgrade to WAS 8.0.0.5+